# SCALA Replace with $

Tags: scala

I want replace a Letter with a **literal** $. I tried:

```
var s = string.replaceAll("Register","$10")
```

I want that this text `Register saved` to be changed to: `$10 saved`

Illegal group reference is the error I get.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the scaladoc for `replaceAll`, you'll see that it takes a regular expression string as the parameter. Escape the `$` with a `\`, or use `replaceAllLiterally`

Answer (score 1):

`replaceAll` uses a regular expressions to find the match.  In the replacement string `$` is a special character that refers to a specific capture group in the matching string.  You have no capture groups so this is an error.  It's not what you want anyway since you want the literal text `"$10"`.

`Use`replace`instead of`replaceAll`.  It just does a direct string replacement.